# ublaboo datagridd get id from latte to presenter

Tags: php, datagrid, nette

I use datagrid Ublaboo\Datagrid on my Nette project.
This DataGrid is super, but I have one problem with get ID from component to presenter.

I have show.latte, that get ID to renderShow method in presenter

```
public function renderShow($id = null) {}
```

This is OK.

And I have in show.latte table list with datagrid.

```
   <div class="table-responsive">
       {control fileList}
    </div>
```

Presenter:

```
public function createComponentFileList($name) {
  // return factory method
  return $grid
}
```

How do I get ID row from show.latte to presenter?

Answer (score 1):

You can't send information from a view (Latte) to a presenter because presenter methods are executed prior to rendering a view.

What do you need that id for? And which id: `renderShow($id = null)` seems to know `$id` already.

You could send information from a component to a presenter in component's method `render()` via `$control->parent` / `$control->presenter`. But again, it's not clear from your question, which id you mean. You don't seem to pass any `$id` from template to `fileList:render()` in `{control fileList}`. Also, at that point, presenter action/render methods have already been executed so I wonder what you'd like to do with that id.

You may have mixed up "presenter" with "component" in your question. You said `renderShow()` is in a presenter but you ask how to pass id from component to presenter.

*"I have show.latte that get ID to renderShow"* isn't a grammatically correct sentence. That adds yet another layer of confusion.